# Mysql : Update archive table after successful transaction in parent table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

In my Java-Spring Boot project, an archive table is created for every customer related tables in MySQL database. On every successful insert or update transaction, I have to create a new record in the archive table with same value being updated in its parent table.

For Example : 
There is a table named as table_1 and its archive table named as table_1_arch. So If a record is inserted in table_1 then table_1_arch should also be updated with a new record with same value inserted in table_1. Similarly If any record is updated in table_1 then table_1_arch should again be updated with a new record with the same value of the record being updated in table_1.

Note:- All archive table has all the columns with same datatypes from its parent table along with two extra columns as table_arch_id and table_arch_flag. This is the schema of a customer table and its archive table.

TABLE_1 :

```
COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_TYPE   IS_NULLABLE   COLUMN_KEY   COLUMN_DEFAULT                       
----------      ------------   -----------   ----------   --------------  
table_1_id      smallint(6)     NO              PRI            (null)                
column_2        varchar(100)    YES                            (null)
```

TABLE_1_ARCH :

```
COLUMN_NAME        COLUMN_TYPE   IS_NULLABLE   COLUMN_KEY   COLUMN_DEFAULT                       
----------         ------------  -----------   ----------   -------------  
table_1_arch_id    smallint(6)     NO              PRI            (null)       
table_1_id         smallint(6)     YES                            (null)                         
column_3           varchar(100)    YES                            (null)                                         
table_1_arch_flag  varchar(1)      YES                            A
```

Comment: Maybe see about replication and/or partitioning

Comment: replication or partitioning is not what I want to do, I already read some articles related to archieve table, mostly those articles deals with copying an amount of data based on a specific date but I want is copy after each successful transaction

Comment: @Madhur, I have edited the question and its pretty clear now. After reading so many articles over internet, I came up with a procedure which is able to do the task which I wanted to. If hold is removed I can post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Enverse. See details here: https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/. Then you get a lot of functionality out of the box.

2) Alternatively, you can use @PrePersist, @PreUpdate, @PreRemove and implement the logic you need.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you do this in the database level so you can achieve this if you are using spring-boot or anything else.
the way to do this is to create `TRIGGER` in mysql, please check the official documentation [MYSQL TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

**EDIT**

for anyone reading this please do not do it using trigger, and check @mentallurg first comment on this answer.

Comment: With a trigger you have no transparency, you can hardly debug it. When you deploy application to some new environment, you should ensure the trigger us created. When you change table structure, you should create each time SQL/DDL to make sure it corresponds to your tables. It is not impossible, but much more effort and more error prone.

Comment: thanks muhammed for your valuable time but doing it database level will not provide much control over it and I may not even achieve what I want

Comment: @mentallurg good point.